# Packer: No AMI was found matching filters

Tags: amazon-web-services, packer

I keep getting the error `No AMI was found matching filters:` when I run packer `build myfile.pkr.hcl`

I am following the basic [tutorial](https://developer.hashicorp.com/packer/tutorials/aws-get-started/aws-get-started-build-image), I've update the `name` of the `source_ami_filter` filter to,

```
source_ami_filter {
  filters = {
    name                = "ubuntu/images/*ubuntu-focal-20.04-amd64-server-*"
    root-device-type    = "ebs"
    virtualization-type = "hvm"
  }
```

Which throws the error,

```
==> dev-server.amazon-ebs.ubuntu: No AMI was found matching filters: {
==> dev-server.amazon-ebs.ubuntu:   Filters: [{
==> dev-server.amazon-ebs.ubuntu:       Name: "name",
==> dev-server.amazon-ebs.ubuntu:       Values: ["ubuntu/images/*ubuntu-focal-20.04-amd64-server-*"]
==> dev-server.amazon-ebs.ubuntu:     },{
==> dev-server.amazon-ebs.ubuntu:       Name: "root-device-type",
==> dev-server.amazon-ebs.ubuntu:       Values: ["ebs"]
==> dev-server.amazon-ebs.ubuntu:     },{
==> dev-server.amazon-ebs.ubuntu:       Name: "virtualization-type",
==> dev-server.amazon-ebs.ubuntu:       Values: ["hvm"]
==> dev-server.amazon-ebs.ubuntu:     }],
==> dev-server.amazon-ebs.ubuntu:   Owners: ["XXXXXXXXXXXX"]
==> dev-server.amazon-ebs.ubuntu: }
Build 'dev-server.amazon-ebs.ubuntu' errored after 1 second 649 milliseconds: No AMI was found matching filters: {
  Filters: [{
      Name: "name",
      Values: ["ubuntu/images/*ubuntu-focal-20.04-amd64-server-*"]
    },{
      Name: "root-device-type",
      Values: ["ebs"]
    },{
      Name: "virtualization-type",
      Values: ["hvm"]
    }],
```

I have also tried the following names:

```
ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-focal-20.04-amd64-server-*  (from AMI marketplace search)
ubuntu/images/*ubuntu-xenial-16.04-amd64-server-*  (this one came from the tutorial)
```

I think at this point something else is going on besides supplying the wrong name but when I supply the `-debug` flag I'm not seeing any additional information.

I have verified my env variables by running `printenv | grep AWS_`

Comment: I need to use `owners      = ["099720109477"]` I was confused and thought this was my AWS ID and its the owner of the AMI.